# Spring Hibernate JPA JSF "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting this error and am about break my nuts to be able to find a solution.

p.s. : I am a total newbie to JPA, Spring and Hibernate.

Error

```
INFO:   13:44:15,065  INFO Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
INFO:   13:44:15,067  INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO:   13:44:15,069  INFO Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name: javassistINFO:   13:44:15,123  INFO Ejb3Configuration:527 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: punit
...]
INFO:   13:44:15,387  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:444 - Destroying singletons in 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f62ebdb: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO:   13:44:15,388 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: punit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: punit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:290)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no user available for com.koski.pms2.User
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getJoin(Ejb3Column.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getTable(Ejb3Column.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.make(SimpleValueBinder.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2036)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:766)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3443)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3397)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactor
SEVERE:   Startup of context /pms2 failed due to previous errors
INFO:   y(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 65 more
SEVERE:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5916)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Application Context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbn2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3305/pms?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="pms"/>
    <property name="password" value="pmspass"/>
</bean>
```

Web.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbn2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3305/pms?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="pms"/>
    <property name="password" value="pmspass"/>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="punit">

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

User.Java class

```
package com.koski.pms2;


import java.io.Serializable;

import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public  class User implements Serializable {


    @Column(name="phone",table="user",nullable=false,length=35)
    @Basic
    private String phone;


    @Column(name="username",table="user",nullable=false,length=70)
    @Basic
    private String username;


    @Column(name="isactive",table="user",nullable=false)
    @Basic
    private boolean isactive;



    @Column(name="email",table="user",nullable=false,length=55)
    @Basic
    private String email;


    @Column(name="user_id",table="user",nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userId;


    @Column(name="password",table="user",nullable=false,length=70)
    @Basic
    private String password;


    public User(){

    }

   public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }


  public void setPhone (String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }



   public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }


  public void setUsername (String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    public boolean isIsactive() {
        return this.isactive;
    }


  public void setIsactive (boolean isactive) {
        this.isactive = isactive;
    }




   public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }


  public void setEmail (String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



   public Integer getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }


  public void setUserId (Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



   public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }


  public void setPassword (String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

any help as soon as possible would be appreciated I do have a deadline.

Comment: Nuri Seker Do you have any `User` entity

Comment: there is a User.java class let me add it to the code.

Comment: "Cannot find the expected secondary table: no user available for com.koski.pms2.User" is your issue. Check if you have a table called user in the DB schema

Comment: doesn't this supposed to create the tables?
<entry key="hibernate.hbn2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is relevant:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no user available for com.koski.pms2.User
```

This happen because Hibernate tries to access User table as secondary table, but it is primary.

It seems that Hibernate expects the table name in the @Column attribute ONLY for the attributes mapped to the secondary table. (This matches the error message)

Try removing table name from your Class properties and should work.

EX.:

```
@Column(name="phone",table="user",nullable=false,length=35)
@Basic
private String phone;
```

Should be :

```
@Column(name="phone", nullable=false, length=35)
@Basic
private String phone;
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, I am very glad that you have pointed it out.
table="user" was the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you should avoid having table names that are reserved words, with hibernate. Sure you can escape it, but it may cause problems in the future (in a query for example). So the safest way is to name the table another way - say users

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's because this has not solved my problem yet?